# Run block defined on class within instance's scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to create something similar to ActiveRecord validation: `before_validate do ... end`. I am not sure how could I reference attributes of class instance from the block given. Any idea?

```
class Something
 attr_accessor :x

 def self.before_validate(&block)
   @before_validate_block = block
 end

 before_validate do
  self.x.downcase
 end

 def validate!
   # how should this method look like? 
   # I would like that block would be able to access instance attributes
 end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@3limin4t0r's answer covers mimicing the behavior in plain ruby very well. But if your are working in Rails you don't need to reinvent the wheel just because you're not using ActiveRecord.

You can use [ActiveModel::Callbacks](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Callbacks.html) to define callbacks in any plain old ruby object:

```
class Something
  extend ActiveModel::Callbacks
  define_model_callbacks :validate, scope: :name

  before_validate do
    self.x.downcase
  end

  def validate!
    run_callbacks :validate do
      # do validations here
    end
  end
end
```

Featurewise it blows the socks off any of the answers you'll get here. It lets define callbacks before, after and around the event and handles multiple callbacks per event.

If validations are what you really are after though you can just include `ActiveModel::Validations` which gives you all the validations except of course `validates_uniqueness_of` which is defined by ActiveRecord.

`ActiveModel::Model` includes all the modules that make up the rails models API and is a good choice if your are declaring a virtual model.

Comment: This looks really great. I am already using ActiveModel::Validations and I see that callbacks are included already. But I am seeing strange error when using: `validates :test_field, presence: true. `NoMethodError: undefined method `before_validate' for #<ActiveModel::Validations::PresenceValidator>`. Any idea why is this error popping out?

Comment: @knagode can you create a new question? I would really need to see a code example to be of any help.

Comment: I created dummy class & question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60667981/how-to-use-activemodels-validations-callbacks-on-custom-class

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved by using [`instance_eval`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_eval) or [`instance_exec`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_exec).

```
class Something
 attr_accessor :x

 # You need a way to retrieve the block when working with the
 # instance of the class. So I've changed the method so it
 # returns the +@before_validate_block+ when no block is given.
 # You could also add a new method to do this.
 def self.before_validate(&block)
   if block
     @before_validate_block = block
   else
     @before_validate_block
   end
 end

 before_validate do
  self.x.downcase
 end

 def validate!
   block = self.class.before_validate # retrieve the block
   instance_eval(&block) # execute it in instance context
 end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
class Something
  attr_accessor :x

  class << self
    attr_reader :before_validate_blocks
    def before_validate(&block)
      @before_validate_blocks ||= []
      @before_validate_blocks << block
    end
  end

  def validate!
    blocks = self.class.before_validate_blocks
    blocks.each {|b| instance_eval(&b)}
  end
end

Something.before_validate do
  puts x.downcase
end

Something.before_validate do
  puts x.size
end

something = Something.new
something.x = 'FOO'
something.validate! # => "foo\n3\n"
```

This version allows us to define multiple validations.