# How to use ActiveModel's Validations & Callbacks on a custom class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to use ActiveModel Validations & Callbacks on custom class.

```
class TestClass
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  define_model_callbacks :validate

  attr_accessor :test_field
  validates :test_field, presence: true # THIS IS CAUSING ISSUES!

  before_validate do 
    test_field.try('upcase!')
  end

  def custom_validate!
    run_callbacks :validate do
      puts "Done"
    end
  end
end
```

But I am receiving the following error:

```
Failure/Error:
  run_callbacks :validate do
    ...
  end
  NoMethodError: 
     undefined method `before_validate' for #<ActiveModel::Validations::PresenceValidator>
```

If I change callback name to something else than `validate` (e.g. `validate_x`) it works. Apparently `validate` is doing a bit more than I would expect. This error only happens if `validates :test_field, presence: true` is defined. For custom `before_validate {}` blocks it doesn't raise errors. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: You could try defining a private method that would run the `try('upcase!')` method. ie `before_validation: :try_case` and then `def try_case; self.test_field.try('upcase!'); end`

Comment: ActiveModel::Validations [appears to already define a `:validate` callback](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4bbd05c90e5a62c0316307b3ca7c2262ed98b567/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations.rb#L54). If you want to define `before_validate` you need to define the callback as `define_callback :validate, scope: :name` - its still puzzling why the built in callback does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The callback name is `before_validation`, just `include ActiveModel::Validations::Callbacks` module too, try this

```
include ActiveModel::Validations
include ActiveModel::Validations::Callbacks

before_validation do 
  test_field.try('upcase!')
end
```

To run custom validation

```
before_validation :custom_validation
```

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/Callbacks/ClassMethods.html#method-i-before_validation

Hope that helps!

Comment: This actually works! It seems like there is some kind of conflict if same callbacks `validate` are set twice (they are already created via ActiveModel::Validations)